I accidentally sent SD coins to a contract address, how can I recover them
I accidentally sent SDs through ethereum to an SD contract address. I can see the tokens on the etherscan. How can I recover them please. I’m willing to send 20% reward for anyone who can help.

This is the transaction ID: 0xc3d1d4683c6b54df9e9e17d5270255a8919c79b4d7ac17b185435ee596d035d3
